# When to use a Property over a Dependency Property in a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10

I've been wondering when should I use a Property or a Dependency Property in a custom control for a while, so I thought it'd be a good idea to ask.

Let's say I have a simple (I mean, really simple) UserControl with just a Button and a TextBlock inside it. Let's call the TextBlock "myTextBlock".

Now, *if* I knew I'll need to bind the Text of that TextBlock to something else, I'd go with a Dependency Property, and that's not a problem.

But what if I *just* need to set the Text property of the TextBlock to a certain value via XAML and leave it be?
Does it matter if I use a Property instead of a DependencyProperty?
Is one option faster/better than the other one, and if so, why?

Here is a sample with the two options:

```
public String ButtonText
{
    get { return (String)GetValue(ButtonTextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ButtonTextProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ButtonText", typeof(String), typeof(MyUserControl),
    new PropertyMetadata(String.Empty, OnButtonTextPropertyChanged));

private static void OnButtonTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (MyUserControl)d.myTextBlock.Text = (String)e.NewValue;
}
```

And with just the Property:

```
public String ButtonText
{
    get { return myTextBlock.Text; }
    set { myTextBlock.Text = value; }
}
```

I usually go with the simple Property, but I don't know if that's the better approach to use here. Of course it works fine, that's not a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Sergio

Comment: It's not only data binding, but also style setters and animations that would require a dependency property. I would always use a dependency property, as it provides greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always ask these basic questions

> Do I need this to be bindable, animations, or styles and have default
>   settings that a simple property can't offer for this control?
>
> Do I need to preserve the XAML (expression) with this new property when I am going to serialize/deserialize this
>   control?

**If yes, then I would use `DependencyProperty`. If not then I'd just use simple properties to be used within this control. It's similar to the question on whether you want to use `fields` vs `properties` in an object. My tip is use it when you need the framework's capabilities in your property as they give you more options. You want to know if you need those options or not.**

**Another reason you want to use DependencyProperty is because you have a base/child control relationship and you want other developers to be able to consume. Instead of you creating interfaces to expose to your control, you provide instant static getter/setter to read/modify the value of your control. You are already creating your interfaces when you create `DependencyProperty`.**

When in doubt, always create simple properties/fields against your control.

*I don't agree with the comment that always go with `DependencyProperty` because it's not cheap compared to a simple property.*

*For example, you want to make changes to the property and it was a `DependencyProperty` then chances are, I would need to manually edit the name of the property which is a `string` and is error-prone. Now compare that to a simple property that gives me a compile time check and I can find the references easily and make some changes to it.*

I've had experiences where `DependencyProperty` was an overkill and should have just used simple properties and the intent would be clear for other developers to read.

Comment: Also, even if all you want is two-way binding (not animation) then you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` with a simple property rather than going all the way to a `DependencyProperty`